# How to get current logged-in user details of a blog in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

When I logged into the specific multi-site blog, I am trying to get current login user details, I already used below one but this function returning null. How, can I get currents logged in user information. I am actually trying to get user email

```
    $logged_in_user = wp_get_current_user();
    wp_get_current_user(); is return below object with empty values  
     WP_User object {
        back_compat_keys => array(6) ( 
                   [user_firstname] => (string) first_name 
                   [user_lastname] => (string) last_name
                   [user_description] => (string) description 
                   [user_level] => (string) wp_user_level 
                   [wp_usersettings] => (string) wp_user-settings 
                   [wp_usersettingstime] => (string) wp_user-settings-time
                 ) 
        data => stdClass object 
        ID => (int) 0 
        caps => array(0) 
        cap_key => null 
        roles => array(0) 
        allcaps => array(0) 
        filter => null 
     };

    //email is
    if($logged_in_user->ID != 0){
        $email = $logged_in_user->user_email;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, comment out this line:

```
 wp_get_current_user(); is return below object with empty values
```

Then, to get user details do this:

```
$userID = $logged_in_user->ID;
$userEmail = $logged_in_user->user_email;
//and so on from there.
```

You can find more examples in [this tutorial here](https://www.freewebmentor.com/2017/06/get-user-details-current-logged-user-wordpress.html).

Comment: If object with empty values how we get                                                      
   $userID = $logged_in_user->ID; // (int)0
   $userEmail = $logged_in_user->user_email; // false

Comment: Why are you using `back_compat_keys()`? What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: In my plugin i am using current user details

Comment: That's for backwards compatibility. What are you trying to be compatible with?